# Database not receiving correct data

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to fill 3 different tables in my database.

1. **Sale** table which has the following rows:

   - sale_id
   - fk_sale_user
   - fk_payment_id
   - sale_date
2. **Print_for_sale** which has:

   - print_for_sale_id
   - fk_sale_id
   - price_print_for_sale
3. **Print_has_size_has_print_for_sale**

   - print_has_size_has_print_for_sale_id
   - fk_print_has_size_id
   - fk_print_for_sale_id

Here is a screenshot of my database in mysql workbench so you can situate.
[image: database]

I'm trying to make the "buying" action.
This is my markup and php code:

**printdetail.php**

```
<?php 


$id= $_GET['print_id'];

$printdetails = getprintdetailsById($con, $id);

$line = mysql_fetch_assoc($printdetails);

$selectsize =" select * from size";

$result=mysql_query($selectsize);

?>


<div>
    <img width="800px;"src="<?php echo $line['print_img']?>"/>
</div>


<div>
    <span> <?php echo $line['print_title']?> </span>
    <form action="addprints.php" method="post">
        <ul>
            <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
                <li> <input type="checkbox" name="sizes[]" value="<?php echo $line['size_id']?>">
              <?php echo $line['size_name']." Price: ".$line['size_price']."€ "?> 
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
            <input type="submit" value="Add to Cart" >
        </ul>
        <input type="hidden" name="print_id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**addprints.php**

```
    <?php
   session_start();
   $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
   print_r($_POST);

   $id_print= $_POST['print_id'];

   include('database.php');

   $bought_sizes=$_POST['sizes'];

   $number_of_bought_sizes= count($bought_sizes);


   //header('location:index.php?area=printstore');


   $sqlinsertsale = "insert into sale
   (fk_sale_user,
   fk_payment_id) 
       values(".$user_id.", 2)";

   mysql_query($sqlinsertsale); 


  for($i=0; $i< $number_of_bought_sizes; $i++){

   $selectsize = "select * 
   from size";

   $resultsize = mysql_query($selectsize);

   while($linesize = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsize))
   { $size_price = $linesize["size_price"]; }


   $selectsale = "select * 
   from sale";

   $resultsale = mysql_query($selectsale);

   while($linesale = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsale))
   { $sale_id = $linesale["sale_id"]; }


   $sqlinsertprintforsale = "insert into print_for_sale
       (fk_sale_id,
       price_print_for_sale) 
       values(".$sale_id.", ".$size_price.")";

   mysql_query($sqlinsertprintforsale);


   $selectprinthassize = "select * 
   from print_has_size";

   $resultprinthassize = mysql_query($selectprinthassize);

   while($lineprinthassize = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultprinthassize))
   { $print_has_size_id = $lineprinthassize["print_has_size_id"]; } 


   $selectprintforsale = "select * 
   from print_for_sale";

   $resultprintforsale = mysql_query($selectprintforsale);

   while($lineprintforsale = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultprintforsale))
   { $print_for_sale_id = $lineprintforsale["print_for_sale_id"]; }     


    $sqlinserthashas = "insert into print_has_size_has_print_for_sale
       (fk_print_has_size_id,
       fk_print_for_sale_id) 
       values(".$print_has_size_id.", ".$print_for_sale_id.")";

   mysql_query($sqlinserthashas);


   } 

   ?>
```

I am very new to php and mysql so I'm sorry if this is a dumb or bad question. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...

- The table **Sale** is being updated correctly in phpmyadmin. Everything is working. User ID is OK and payment ID is OK too. (*I haven't done the payments part yet so I just used a number to test.*)

The table **Print_for_sale** is updating the correct sale ID (fk_sale_id), however the price_print_for_sale is always the same, no matter what print I choose. It's always 150 when sometimes it should be 65 ou 25.
(The print price is defined in the **size** table. So far I have 3 different sizes, so different prices.)

The table **Print_has_size_has_print_for_sale** is updating the correct print_for_sale ID, but the fk_print_has_size_id is always number 12 (which is the last from that list) and it has nothing to do with my choices on the form. I believe this is what is making the price come out wrong. If it's always the same combination of prints and size (print_has_size), then it's always going to have the same price... Why is this happening?

Can someone please help me?

Here are some screenshots of phpmyadmin:

[image: print_has_size_table]

[image: sale_table]
[image: print_for_sale_table]
[image: print_has_size_has_print_for_sale_table]

Edit: This is the function I used:

```
<?php

function getprintdetailsById($con, $print_id){
    $question = "select * from print where print_id=".$print_id;

    $result = mysql_query($question, $con);

    return $result;
    }

  ?>
```

Comment: none of that code makes much sense. you're doing queries in nested loops, and always running the SAME queries inside the loops.You also have absolutely no error handling and are simply assuming none of your query calls could ever fail.

Comment: Can you also show `getprintdetailsById` function?

Comment: This question is too specific to your exact code and db setup and too absurdly long to help anyone in the future. And the code needs to be rewritten to use PDO or mysqli rather than the deprecated `mysql_` extension anyway, so you might as well start over.

Comment: Already did @Arian :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot of info.. I guess we can start debugging. Let's begin with your while loops. Inside your for loop, the first line `select * from size`, this should return an array, then you are iterating this array with your while loop, but you are assigning them to just one variable. This will overwrite the data result of the last iteration. Is this what you want?... to be continued.

You don't want that to be overwritten.. so what you need to do for that while loop is assign it to an array, like this:

```
while ($linesize = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultsize)) {
    $size_price[] = $linesize["size_price"];
}
```

so, once you have the `$size_price[]` with all the desired sizes, we move on.. your code now runs `select * from sale` where you want all the `sale_ids` from. So just like above, assign it to an array, we'll say `$sale_ids[]`

Now you are trying to run a query that inserts data to the `print_for_sale` table, but the data comes from the two different arrays you created above.. this is will not work, and if so, you would need to come up with crazy loops and iteration like you already have tried.

To fix it, you first need to look at your tables, assign them unique ids, and link them through indexes, once you do that, you need to use the `JOIN` SQL  command on your queries to get the matched data together.

I would look into separating your code as well. this will help you reuse it. You should look into an MVC framework. Ever heard of Codeigniter? its very easy to learn and powerful for applications.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you :) 
No! I don't want the data to be overwrited. How can I fix that?

Comment: Now I get these two errors Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/printstore/addprints.php on line 66

Notice: Array to string conversion in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/printstore/addprints.php on line 66

because i'm using the values like this: values(".$sale_id.", ".$size_price.")"; :S

Comment: Will you be free in like two hours? I can help you more in fixing your code, perhaps even through Teamviwer... Let me know

Comment: Yes i will! I will try teamviewer then. How can I find you? @CodeGodie

Comment: good question.. do you have yahoo messenger?

Comment: yes, it's owlyac@yahoo.com @CodeGodie thank you :)

Comment: you're welcome buddy, I will contact you later, set some time aside so we can work on that. chat u then.

Comment: Thank you so much! @CodeGodie I'll be waiting then :)

Comment: youre welcome. Hope it all worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could use work, but I think that your problem is a misplaced bracket at the end. It should be:

```
while($lineprinthassize = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultprinthassize))
{
   $print_has_size_id = $lineprinthassize["print_has_size_id"];
   $selectprintforsale = "select * 
   from print_for_sale";

   $resultprintforsale = mysql_query($selectprintforsale);
    while($lineprintforsale = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultprintforsale))
       {
       $print_for_sale_id = $lineprintforsale["print_for_sale_id"];
        $sqlinserthashas = "insert into print_has_size_has_print_for_sale
           (fk_print_has_size_id,
           fk_print_for_sale_id) 
           values(".$print_has_size_id.", ".$print_for_sale_id.")";
       mysql_query($sqlinserthashas);
       }
}
```

The replace code should be in the loop. In your original code, you looped through all the values, ending with the last one, and then used it.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but it gives me the same problem... Always the same price and always the same print_has_size ID  :(

Comment: You are right, I overlooked that. You actually need to extend the last **two** loops. I've updated the answer.